# onsubmit function is not being called

Tags: javascript, function, onsubmit

I am designin a shoutbox which is AJAX based.
http://businessgame.be/shoutbox.php

The script works perfectly in google chrome, but other browsers don't act like I expect.

To shout a new message, there is a form which owns a input text field. When pressing enter, the form is being submitted, so I have omitted a submit button since pressing enter is sufficient.

```
<form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="javascript: return shout();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" style="width: 100%;" name="txtShout" id="txtShout" maxlength="600" autocomplete="off" title="Shout!" placeholder="Shout!">
</form>
```

The shout function looks like this:

```
function shout() {
alert("test");
        // Post shout and clear textField
        if(getLength("txtShout")) {
            AjaxUpdate("./includes/shout.php?message=" + getItemValue("txtShout"), refreshShoutBox);
            setItemValue("txtShout", "");
        }

        // Stop submit
        return false;
    }
```

Normally, the script should call the shout function, the AJAX would send a request to add the shout and then return false so the form does not get submitted.

But in all browsers except Google Chrome, the form gets submitted anyway. I put in an alert() in the function to check if it was called or a coding mistake but the alert is not being shown.

Comment: Have you tried onsubmit="return shout();" without the 'javascript:'?

Comment: Yes, this does not solve the problem. The alert is not even showing so I guess the browser is just skipping the onsubmit statement...

I also tried changing the function to an alert only but it doesn't work :/.

Comment: In that case, sounds like you should check it with Firebug.  You can use firebug's console to find JavaScript errors.

Comment: That just gives no extra information, the function is not getting called, there is no error given or anything...

Comment: There must be some kind of error.  The syntax for binding it is right, so it must be some kind of error in the JS that Chrome will tolerate and other browsers will not (or something used that only exists in Chrome).  Also, if there is an error, it might not even be in that function, and it may still affect that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for some reason, I couldn't get the onsubmit function working in other browsers. Instead of desperately keep looking to fix it a decided to go for a different approach. Now I just added a listener to the text box to check when a key is pressed if it was the enter key and then call that function.

That seemed to work, still had to remove the form though, because otherwise it would get submitted ^^.

So now I got something like this:

```
function shoutEnterListener() {
    // Get object
    var domObject = document.getElementById("txtShout");

    // Get shoutbox html code
    if(domObject) {
        domObject.onkeydown = shoutEnter;
        domObject.onkeypress = shoutEnter;
    }
}

function shoutEnter(e) {
    var keyCode;

    // Check which key has been pressed
    if (window.event) {
        keyCode = window.event.keyCode;
    } else {
        keyCode = e.which;
    }

    // If enter, shout!
    if (keyCode == 13) {
        shout();
    }
}
```

The shoutEnterListener() is called in the init function. This also proves that there wasn't a coding error whatsoever but purely the function not being called at all.

If you still find the solution to the previous problem, let me know, because this is a bit tedious and intensive code.